# Would a repeated measures MANOVA be appropriate for a 9DV, 2IV within subjects study design?

Tags: mixed-model, manova, research-design, gpower

I am trying to get an estimate of participants to strive for in my study. Being rather new to the research and stats scene, I was hoping the community could help me out a little bit?

The study has 9 dependent variables:

**Prepost measures:**

- Standardized score 1 (UPDRS score)
- Standardized score 2 (An objective score)
- Entropy of raw numbers that make up standardized score 2

**Measures taken throughout the experimental sessions:**

- Max value of EEG spectral powers
- Mean value of EEG spectral powers
- Mean value of EEG frequency
- Max value of EMG amplitude
- Correlational measure 1 (correlates EEG and EMG, called corticomuscular coherence)
- Correlational measure 2 (same as 1, but with direction)

**And 2 independent variables:**

- Experimental session A
- Experimental session B

Each participant will be taking part in both sessions, in a different order.

**Research question:** We would like to know whether Experimental session A has a greater effect on our dependent variables than session B.

Given that we have 2+ IV and 2+ DV I figured a repeated measures MANOVA would be the way to go, or maybe a stepwise regression multivariate model. I am a bit torn on how to carry out the GPower apriori calculation to get an estimated optimal sample size.

**So I have two main questions:**

- Would repeated measures MANOVA or the regression model best answer the questions? Or perhaps something else? My confusion comes from how some DV are interrelated (or calculated) from others (entropy scores, directional coherence), while other DV are completely separate (UPDRS score)
- How do I find the "variance explained by special effect" and "variance within groups" parts of gPower? After searching online, it seems like the general recommendation is to create a mock-dataset with an estimated mean/standard deviation and get the variance from that. Do I do this for all 9 dependent variables and take the average variation from that?
- How can I calculate the "correlation among repeated measures" portion of the gPower input parameter?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!